# Is it possible to insert more than one image in a cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to insert more than two images in one cell. Is it possible?

I tried to use the command `IMAGE(url)`, but it just allowed to insert one image...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is not possible to insert more than one image in a cell.

Actually what the cells are embedded in functions that return a result, or a single value for a variable.

To insert images, all you can do is insert the url of the image on the =IMAGE(url) function, which transforms this url in their graphic representation, so if the function only lets you add a single image, that is all you can do.

Anyway, as you can not insert an array of elements in a cell, why you want to insert multiple images in a cell?

You can try the menu Insert Image: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/97447?hl=en&rd=2

Comment: Hi Juan C.V. , thanks very much for the answer. I just learn how to use google sheets and want to create a text cell, which I can input text messages with some smilies. :)