# multiple images in one cell (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

How I can insert multiple images to one cell in Google Sheets?

This code not working for multiple images in one cell:

```
=IMAGE("https://www.wikihow.com/images/thumb/d/db/Get-the-URL-for-Pictures-Step-2-Version-6.jpg/aid597183-v4-728px-Get-the-URL-for-Pictures-Step-2-Version-6.jpg.webp") =IMAGE("https://media.wired.com/photos/5b8999943667562d3024c321/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/trash2-01.jpg")
```

Comment: Please find the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32424270/1527780)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to insert more than one image in a cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32424270/is-it-possible-to-insert-more-than-one-image-in-a-cell)

Comment: change width of two neighboring columns to half. insert 2 pictures into two neighboring cells. and then remove border between those cells